# remove one duplicate value from two columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have the table as following

```
| country | state |
--------------------
| USA     | MH    |
| USA     | PB    |
| USA     | KN    |
| USA     | TN    |
| USA     | CG    |
| USA     | MH    |
```

I have now two values of

```
| country | state |
--------------------
| USA     | MH    |
| USA     | PB    |
```

and i just want to remove single

```
| country | state |
--------------------
| USA     | MH    |
```

so my table will look like

```
| country | state |
--------------------
| USA     | MH    |
| USA     | PB    |
| USA     | KN    |
| USA     | TN    |
| USA     | CG    |
```

please help me with this

thank you in advanced

Comment: Do you know about "Select Distinct"?  Look that up

Answer (score 2):

```
select distinct country,state from table1 T1
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually removing the duplicates from the table is a bit difficult because the table does not have a primary key.  One method is to copy the data to a new table and re-insert it:

```
create temporary table temp_t as
    select distinct country, state
    from t;

truncate table t;

insert into t(country, state)
    select country, state
    from temp_t;
```